# Who is in charge of county-level redistricting in each state?

Tags: united-states, local-government, voting-districts, redistricting

Many counties elect commissioners, who represent a district within the county.  Who is in charge of drawing these lines in each state?

Note: Not looking for state level offices like the State House of Representatives - I am referring to districts of county officials only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on which county you're talking about. Every state is different, and within some states, every county, city, or other municipal entity can differ, to boot.

Generally speaking, municipal entities (which includes counties) are legally extensions of the state government - so at some level the state legislature is in charge of redistricting insofar as it decides who to delegate it to, if they do delegate it.

Those states that do delegate it, for example, [Washington](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=35A.12.180), have to provide for the method of such divisions in the authorizing statute. Generally speaking, they will require the municipality to define the process in its chartering document. (Basically the Constitution, but for the municipal entity.)

Beyond that, you'll have to be far more specific.

Comment: Almost every state handles local redistricting locally even though it is not constitutionally required to do so. Sometimes there is a county election board appointed in some particular way (e.g. Ohio), sometimes the body itself draws its new districts.